# Случайная пара Python

Tags: python

Есть список пользователей. Надо сделать так, чтобы код распределял каждому пользователю случайного пользователя (составлял пару). Как это реализовать?
Если проходиться циклом for, то будут повторы.

Comment: шаффл списку, забирать последовательные пары.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перемешать список, забирать последовательные пары:

```
import random


lst = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(lst)
for a, b in zip(*[iter(lst)] * 2):
    print(a, b)
```

> ```
> 9 5
> 2 1
> 3 0
> 4 8
> 7 6
> ```

Comment: Прикольный приём с удвоением итератора )

Comment: @CrazyElf, [документация по zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), "Tips and tricks".